# Add custom header in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, header, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I need to add some custom headers to the `HttpWebRequest` object. How can I add Custom Header to  `HttpWebRequest` object in Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You use the `Headers` property with a string index:

```
request.Headers["X-My-Custom-Header"] = "the-value";
```

According to MSDN, this has been available since:

- Universal Windows Platform 4.5
- .NET Framework 1.1
- Portable Class Library
- Silverlight 2.0
- **Windows Phone Silverlight 7.0**
- **Windows Phone 8.1**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: also the string can be replaced with enum HttpRequestHeader like this httpWebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "value";

Comment: That would not answer the original question, @OXXY . The `HttpRequestHeader` enumeration is for standard headers – not for custom ones.

Comment: there is a property called name in google drive file upload api, which should be sent via post method. So, 
request.Headers["name"] = "hello.txt";
So, its not reflecting. 
Any Help
What should we use for custom ones?

Comment: POST data is not sent through Headers, so this is not the right place for your question. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 24):

A simple method of creating the service, adding headers and reading the JSON response,

```
private static void WebRequest()
    {
        const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "<<Web service URL>>";
        try
        {
            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.Method = "GET";
                webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic dchZ2VudDM6cGFdGVzC5zc3dvmQ=");

                using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                    {
                        var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Response: {0}", jsonResponse));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Authorization` is not a custom header, and should be handled in a more controlled way.

Answer (score 2):

You can add values to the HttpWebRequest.Headers collection.

According to MSDN, it should be supported in windows phone:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to visit the web page from where you are trying to fetch response.
Right Click>Inspect>Network>(Refresh it)> Under Name Click on the first Link>Now you can see the Request Headers and Response  Headers

From there you you can see the Request Headers and add them accordingly
Like an example:

HttpWebRequest HttpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

```
        HttpWReq.Method = "GET";
        HttpWReq.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        HttpWReq.Headers.Add("cache-control", "max-age=0");
         HttpWReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36";
        HttpWReq.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        HttpWReq.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
        HttpWReq.Headers.Add("cache-control", "max-age=0");
        HttpWReq.Headers.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");
```