# Windows Phone 8 Http request with custom header

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, webclient, windows-phone-8

I want to send a HTTP PUT request to a WCF server from Windows Phone 8, and for identification I have to send a custom header. (assume "mycustomheader" = "abc")

I was using `WebClient` so far, but the `Webclient.Headers` seems not to have an `Add` method, so it is not possible to send headers other then the ones in `HttpRequestHeader` enum. Is there any way to do this with `WebClient`?

---

I saw it is possible to set a custom header with `HttpWebRequest` class, but I just can't get it to do anything at all. My test code (basically the sample copied from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx):

```
public void dosth()
{
    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mycomputer/message");
    wr.Method = "PUT";
    wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    wr.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), wr);
    allDone.WaitOne();
}

private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
    string postData = "{'Command': { 'RequestType' : 'Status', 'Test' : '1' }}";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
    postStream.Close();
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
}

private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
    streamResponse.Close();
    streamRead.Close();
    response.Close();
    allDone.Set();
}
```

As I can see with wireshark: nothing is arriving at my computer (same url and everything works fine with `WebClient` .. except for the custom header). In debugging I can see the `GetRequestStreamCallback` being fired and running through. But it never arrives in the `GetResponseCallback`. Most stuff I find regarding this refers to methods like `GetResponse()` that seem not to be available on

Whats is the way to go here? Is it possible to get the `HttpWebRequest` to work, or is there some workaround to get the custom header set in `WebClient` or is there even another better way?

---

edit: webclient code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = data.Length.ToString();
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://mycomputer/message"), "PUT", data);
```

sends the correct data to the correct url. However setting custom header seems not to be possible. (even tried \r\n inside a header ... but this is not allowed and throws exception)

Comment: Can you proved the `WebClient` code which worked fine ?

Comment: Did you try this `wc.Headers["some header"] = "header value";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom header in HttpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519788/add-custom-header-in-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you set the header?
Here is how to do it:

```
request.Headers["mycustomheader"] = "abc";
```

Comment: Jea i know that. The problem with the httpWebRequest code is that there is no request arriving at the server whatsoever

Comment: @Flo - So update your question to reflect you trying to do thattt?

Comment: i thought i made that clear. I want to send a request with customheaders. I tried sending a request with WebClient. It works. But I cant find a way to set custom header there. I tried sending a request with HttpWebRequest because i found that setting a customheader is possible there. Cant get it to work at all. Nothing arriving at my server. The command for setting the header really isnt the problem when I can get it to work. What to do?

Comment: Must have been some IntelliSense fail, I tried that multiple times and VisualStudio showed errors .. but some time later it did work .. I dont get it, but am happy that it works now.