# Need to code a CURL command to VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, curl

I need to code this Curl/json command on VB.net. I am not sure how to use HttpWebRequest. Please HELP!!!

curl -X GET --header "Accept: */*" --header "X-Auth-Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTc3NTQ1" "http://staging-exact-integration.posios.com/PosServer/rest/core/company"

Comment: C#, not VB.net but maybe this will point you in the right direction: [Add custom header in HttpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519788/add-custom-header-in-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is what you're after.

To add headers, you simply create a custom HttpRequestMessage:

```
Dim client As New HttpClient()
Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage() With
{
     .RequestUri = New Uri("http://staging-exact-integration.posios.com/PosServer/rest/core/company"),
     .Method = HttpMethod.Get,
}

request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTc3NTQ1")

Dim result = client.SendAsync(request).Result
```

Comment: Thanks "Uno" it looks like is taking the token now. What I need to do now is to save the results on a json format and show them somehow.I will appreciate some help!!!

Comment: No problem ;). The result will be a HttpResponseMessage, and result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync should give you back the JSON data as a string.