# Code header.add not working in .net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

How to add the header in the WebRequest .

```
 HttpWebRequest tRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "POST";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new
            {
                to = devicesId,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "Fcm Test Notification",
                    title = "Test FCM",
                    sound = "Enabled"
                },
                priority = "high"
            };

            tRequest.Headers["Authorization: key={0}"] = appId;

            tRequest.Headers["Sender: id={0}"] = senderId;
```

i need to add the header to create the web Request.

Thanks

Comment: Its duplicated already answer here.
[Add custom header in HttpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37430845/2337983)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom header in HttpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519788/add-custom-header-in-httpwebrequest)

Comment: Not duplicated, read my answer

Answer (score 0):

Missing `Add` in `HttpWebRequest` is because have missing `ISerializable` in CoreFx (so you can not simply `tRequest.Headers.Add("name", "value");`). They working on it and you can follow at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12669