# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Search requests cannot accept content streams in Solr4

Tags: c#, solr, lucene

I am using Solr 4. I have a very long query to search for (URI too long).
So I am using POST method with JSON request content to search using HttpWebRequest in C#.
But getting error as "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.".
I checked in Solr log which shows the error as "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Search requests cannot accept content streams".
But everything is working in Solr 7.
Is there any way to search in Solr 4 for very long query? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "Content-Type" header on the request

Changing it to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" should do the trick.

See following link to set header on HttpWebRequest: [Add custom header in HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519788/add-custom-header-in-httpwebrequest)

EDIT: Please make sure to use POST request. In URL only enter the end point and add the query as request body.

Comment: Sorry, it did not work.
I tried this : 

`HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);`
`request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`
`request.Method = "POST";`
`HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`


In Solr 7, it throws error as "The remote server returned an error: (414) URI Too Long".
In Solr 4, it throws error as "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".

Comment: It seems you are specifying the query in URL only. You can specify query in request body also.

Comment: Please show me the way with example. As I have mentioned earlier that Solr 4 is not accepting content streams when I was sending request body in JSON format.

Comment: Can you please specify the URL you are using?

Comment: From the error it seems that you are entering your solr query in URL. In the code you shared in comments it shows that you are hitting a URL but I did not see what URL you are hitting. I also did not understand where you are setting the form body. Maybe if you can share the complete code snippet, I can help further.